# Make a multiple form with add more form button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp

I have sample multiple textbox.
but it just can make one textbox.
I want make multiple form with button add form. this in my sample

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function appendRow()
{
   var d = document.getElementById('plus');
   d.innerHTML += "<input type='text' name='nama'><br >";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Crud_insert_multiple" method="POST">
 <input type="button" onclick ="appendRow()" value="Add Text Boxt">
 <table>
 <tr><td>Nama</td><td><div id='plus'></div></td></tr>
 <tr>
 <td></td>
 <td><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the action form.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Database db = (Database) getServletContext().getAttribute("db");
    String[] a=request.getParameterValues("nama");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        try {
            String sql = "insert into user(username) values('"+a[i]+"')";
            db.updateSql(sql);

        } catch (Exception e2) {
            System.out.println(e2);
        }
    }
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/crud_select.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

> how can I make a multiple form?
>   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the input name to accept multiple values (in array)

```
d.innerHTML += "<input type='text' name='nama[]'><br >";
```

Comment: I am not familiar with jsp, but I thought it's already expecting an array of values. If not, you need to do the change. ( request.getParameterValues("nama") will be an array of values you have put in the boxes). For example if you have two input boxes with "Text1" and "Text2", a javascript array representation of request.getParameterValues("nama") will be = ["Text1", "Text2"] .
Sorry, I just don't know how to make the  change in jsp.

Comment: Have you tried with making this change? Not sure, but as I see your jsp code, it seems like it's already handling it as an array.

Comment: Even if the texboxes are many, the server side will receive only one input putting all values in an array.